# Cts and Xmdp functions in marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I want to use   xdmp.addResponseHeader and cts.element range query in my node js api. can anyone suggest me how to use these functions in my api .

Comment: Those are server-side functions, how would you like to use them client-side?

Comment: Or to put differently, what are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to write post function in node js on marklogic search using structured query and want to use range-query. how can i do that?

Comment: The search dev guide is your friend: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_83393

Comment: And if you are using the node client api, you might wanna checkout the node dev guide as well: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/search#id_28266